# jQuery UI Tabs: What's the simplest way to get a # for each tab in the browser and in the URL?

Tags: url, jquery-ui-tabs

**What's the simplest way to get a # for each tab in the browser bar and in the URL?**

I've look through lots of SO questions and answers. I don't need the jQuery Tabs UI address plugin that gives back/forward browser button capability. I'm not loading content via Ajax.

All I need is the hash in the browser bar, i.e. `mydomain.com/#tab3`. I can link to that tab by direct URL, i.e. `http://mydomain.com/#tab3` but the hash doesn't show in the browser bar when on that tab unless it's manually entered, and then it doesn't change when the tab is changed.

**Basic tabs init I'm working with:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var $tabs= $("#tabs").tabs();

$('.home').click(function() { $tabs.tabs('select', 1); return false;});
$('.about').click(function() { $tabs.tabs('select', 2); return false;});
$('.books').click(function() { $tabs.tabs('select', 3); return false;});

$(function() {
$('#tabs').tabs({
fx : { 
opacity: 'toggle' 
}

});
});
```

**Basic Tabs html:**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>

<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>

</ul>

<div id="home"> blah bah...</div>

<div id="about"> blah bah...</div>

<div id="books"> blah bah...</div></div>
```

**Linking:**

This will link to a tab via URL  - `mydomain.com/#about`  - but will not show the # in the browser bar without entering it manually:

```
<a href="#about" class="about" title="About">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use:

```
<a href="#about" onClick="location.href='#about'" class="about" title="About">About</a>
```